# Dynamic help command - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a "dynamic" help menu command for my Discord bot. Now my commands work with "normal" messages. But I want to use Embed. So, let me explain.
Basically, I do `re!help` and the bot sends an Embed. Then I add two reactions ("◀" and "▶"), and if I click on a reaction (eg "▶") the Embed is updated with the commands (I want both the title and the description of the Embed to be updated). I hope I was clear and if you did not understand what I want tell me I will try to explain it again. Here is my code anyway:

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    contents = [
"""
text 1
""",
"""
text 2
""",
"""
text 3    
""",
"""
text 4
"""]
    pages = 4
    cur_page = 1
    message = await ctx.send(f"{contents[cur_page-1]}")
    # getting the message object for editing and reacting

    await message.add_reaction("◀️")
    await message.add_reaction("▶️")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]
        # This makes sure nobody except the command sender can interact with the "menu"

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
            # waiting for a reaction to be added - times out after x seconds, 60 in this
            # example

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                cur_page += 1
                await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                cur_page -= 1
                await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                # removes reactions if the user tries to go forward on the last page or
                # backwards on the first page
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            break
```

Wish someone could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `contents` being a list of strings, make it a list of embeds, then edit the message appropiately

```py
contents = [
    discord.Embed(title="page 1"), 
    discord.Embed(title="page 2"), 
    discord.Embed(title="page 3"),
    discord.Embed(title="page 4")
]

...

await message.edit(
    content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}",
    embed=contents[cur_page - 1]
)
```

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll check the question mark if it will work!